# Page Inspector doesn't handle New Windows from Javascript

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, page-inspector

I have an ASP.NET application I've inherited and am trying to debug. I'm using Page Inspector in VS 2012 Express to work on a particular page that has lots of JS in it. Unfortunately, that page is opened as a popup whose URL is dynamically generated by JS. Page Inspector does not seem to handle this well.

If it just popped out into the new window, that would be OK because I could then get the URL and paste it back into the main PI window. However, it seems to lose the session reference when it pops up, because it logs me out of the application, and when I log back in I lose the location I was at.

I've tried changing the function that does the URL generation / window opening to a window.location.href, but that doesn't seem to work either; it just stays on the same page.

The references to the URL generation functions are done in such a way that it would be a lot of work to switch it from calling a JS function to just a straight link on the page, especially since I would have to switch it back for production.

Any ideas on how I can configure Page Inspector to handle popup windows better?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the page inspector, but can't you use the browser's debugger for that? Or, if you need to know the URL, can't you inspect elements with the browser and get the URL from there?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I could come up with a workaround of some kind, but I was hoping to find an elegant solution. Page Inspector seems like a really great idea so you don't have to keep stopping and starting debugging. However, I've pretty much given up for now and am using Firefox with Firebug.